# Regex to find attributes without using lookbehinds

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a regex in JS that will match attributes with the following syntax `@scope.name`:

- They start with an @ sign
- The scope and name of the attribute is separated by a period
- Only letters are supported, and numbers/underscores as well as long as they are not in the beginning of the scope or name.

Escaped @ signs are represented like this "@@", and they should be ignored. Here are some examples of some expected behaviors I'm looking for:

| String | Match 1 | Group 1 | Match 2 | Group 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `a.b` | *No match* | - | *No match* | - |
| `@a.b` | @a.b | a.b | *No match* | - |
| `@@a.b` | *No match* | - | *No match* | - |
| `@@@a.b` | @a.b | a.b | *No match* | - |
| `@a.b@@c.d@@@e.f` | @a.b | a.b | @e.f | e.f |

The current regex I have - `/(?<=(?<!@)(?:@@)*)@([a-zA-Z]\w*\.[a-zA-Z]\w*)/` - doesn't work on Safari because lookbehinds aren't supported yet. I need a solution that doesn't use them.

[Here's](https://regex101.com/r/lx2mL5/1) the regex101 url to test your expressions and compare the results to the expected ones I have currently.

Comment: Use `/(@?)(?:@@)*@([a-zA-Z]\w*\.[a-zA-Z]\w*)/g`, if Group 1 is not undefined, cancel the match. Else, get Group 2 value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a lookbehind you can use a non-capture group with expected pattern preceding your capture group:

```js
[ 'a.b', '@a.b', '@@a.b', '@@@a.b', '@a.b@@c.d@@@e.f', '@a_.b_', '@_a.b', '@a.b_'
].forEach(str => {
  let result = [...str.matchAll(/(?:^|[^@]|@@)@([a-zA-Z]\w*\.[a-zA-Z]\w*)/g)];
  console.log({
    str,
    result: result.length ? result.map(r => r[1]).join(', ') : 'no match'
  });
});
```

Explanation of regex:

- `(?:^|[^@]|@@)` -- non-capture group: either start of string, a non `@` char, or two consecutive `@` chars
- `@` -- literal `@` char
- `([a-zA-Z]\w*\.[a-zA-Z]\w*)` -- your original capture group

Answer (score 0):

I'd first replace all `@@` with a special char (not letter, number, or underscore), then use simplified regex `@(\w+\.\w+)`

```js
const strings=[
'a.b',
'@a.b',
'@@a.b',
'@@@a.b',
'@a.b@@c.d@@@e.f']

const modified=strings.map(s=>s.replaceAll('@@','*'))

modified.forEach(s=>{
  let result=[...s.matchAll(/@(\w+\.\w+)/g)]
  console.log(s)
  if(result.length){
    console.log('matches: ',result.map(r=>r[1]).join(', '))
  }else{
    console.log('No match')
  }
})
```